# How to run event after scripts?

Tags: jquery

how to run the event after loading all my scripts? I mean this:

```
$('body').attr('onload', 'Scrollbar()');
```

I trying to run this event only after loading all my scripts

```
<body onload="Scrollbar()">
```

My scripts are before **/body** tag at the bottom of the document like this

```
    <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried more, it does not work for me either

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
$(window).on('load', function() { ... });
```

**Is possible do this?**

**EDIT**

**Scrollbar()** function:

```
function Scrollbar(){new SmoothScroll(document,65,15)}function SmoothScroll(o,n,t){o==document&&(o=document.documentElement||document.body.parentNode||document.body);var i=!1,a=o.scrollTop;function e(e){e.preventDefault();var t=e.delta||e.wheelDelta;void 0===t&&(t=-e.detail),t=Math.max(-1,Math.min(1,t)),a+=-t*n,a=Math.max(0,Math.min(a,o.scrollHeight-o.clientHeight+15)),i||m()}function m(){i=!0;var e=(a-o.scrollTop)/t;o.scrollTop+=e,.0<Math.abs(e)?d(m):i=!1}o.addEventListener("mousewheel",e,!1),o.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",e,!1);var d=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(e){window.setTimeout(e,20)}}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheCzechTayen/edh8zxjr/1/)**

Comment: $(window).on('load', function() {});// this is a solution for execute code when page is fully loaded...I think theres something else here...if you can add a http://jsfiddle.net code will be better to trace ... any way try to set your code in setTimeout inside $(window).on('load', function() { ... });...and check if its work as you like or no...

Comment: Is it possible that I got it right, just added the attribute and did not activate the event?

Comment: maybe yes...so that I tell you to setTimeout inside load...plz, try to execute this $(window).on('load', function() {   setTimeout(function(){alert('xxxxx')}, 1000)  });...also set your code after alert ...and see if popup is showing and your code execute as you want or no...yoo need to try to run event after attribute is added...

Comment: Popup works but my code still nope. My question is updated, look. This works only when I put jquery and this code before BODY (before this onload event) but this does not work like this, is the error somewhere in the code?

Comment: You title says "How to run event before JS?", but your first sentence is "how to run the event after loading all my scripts?", which is the precise opposite. Please edit your title to be in line with the question. Also, please add any error messages you are getting and what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: No errors here, log is clear. With $(window).on('load', function() { ... }) no error here, but script probably does not run.

Comment: I suggest to add your code here http://jsfiddle.net/, and share link for us to can help you...

Comment: My question is uploaded, the jsFiddle link attached

Comment: use jquery $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is invalid:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('body').attr('onload', 'Scrollbar()');
});
```

You are adding a `onload` attribute to body after full page load, so it will not work as body `onload` was triggered already...
To fix this issue please use this code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
     Scrollbar();
});
```

It executes `Scrollbar()` directly after page load. `$(document).ready()` should also do the job well.

Comment: Nope. Your code does not work, it throws a error Scrollbar is not defined. Your event triggered before the scripts.js loads. $(document).ready() does not work too, the same error

Comment: Morning @TheCzechTayen if you have `Scrollbar` defined in the same file as `$(window).on('load')` and the `Scrollbar` is defined as first in file it should work. This is what I read from the jsFiddle... :) Am I missing something?